# Times font error using tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat

Tags: tikz-qtree, times

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{bussproofs}%
\usepackage{cgloss4e,gb4e}%


\newcommand{\PP}{{\.{p}}}
\newcommand{\K}{\d{k}}
\newcommand{\LL}{\textlambda}
\newcommand{\LI}{\d{\textlambda}}
\newcommand{\E}{\textipa{@}}
\newcommand{\R}{\textipa{K}}
\newcommand{\W}{\textipa{\super w}}
\newcommand{\I}{\textipa{P}}
\newcommand{\C}{\textipa{\d{c}}}
\newcommand{\Ch}{\v{c}}
\newcommand{\CCh}{\d{\v{c}}}
\newcommand{\Sh}{\v{s}}
\newcommand{\SSh}{\d{\v{s}}}
\newcommand{\Zh}{\v{z}}
\newcommand{\ZZh}{\d{\v{z}}}
\newcommand{\Shh}{\^{s}}
\newcommand{\SShh}{\d{\^{s}}}
\newcommand{\Zhh}{\^{z}}
\newcommand{\Dzh}{\textipa{\v{Z}}}
\newcommand{\Dz}{\textipa{Z}}
\newcommand{\TShh}{\textipa{\t{t\text{\^{s}}}}}
\newcommand{\TSShh}{\textipa{\t{t\text{\d{\^{s}}}}}}%Bzhedug affricate
\newcommand{\X}{\textipa{X}}
\newcommand{\G}{\textipa{G}}

\newcommand{\abs}{\textsc{abs}}
\newcommand{\add}{\textsc{add}}
\newcommand{\adv}{\textsc{adv}}
\newcommand{\aux}{\textsc{ipf}}
\newcommand{\ben}{\textsc{ben}}
\newcommand{\caus}{\textsc{caus}}
\newcommand{\cnv}{\textsc{cvb}}
\newcommand{\com}{\textsc{com}}
\def\comp{\textsc{comp}}
\newcommand{\cond}{\textsc{cond}}
\newcommand{\coord}{\textsc{coord}}
\newcommand{\dat}{\textsc{dat}}
\newcommand{\dem}{\textsc{dem}}
\newcommand{\dir}{\textsc{dir}}
\newcommand{\dyn}{\textsc{dyn}}
\newcommand{\Emph}{\textsc{emph}}
\newcommand{\erg}{\textsc{erg}}
\newcommand{\habit}{\textsc{habit}}
\newcommand{\hbl}{\textsc{hbl}}
\newcommand{\fut}{\textsc{fut}}
\newcommand{\inadv}{\textsc{inadv}}
\newcommand{\indef}{\textsc{indef}}
\newcommand{\Inf}{\textsc{inf}}
\newcommand{\ins}{\textsc{ins}}
\newcommand{\intr}{\textsc{intr}}
\newcommand{\io}{\textsc{io}}
\newcommand{\ipf}{\textsc{ipf}}
\newcommand{\Lim}{\textsc{lim}}
\newcommand{\lnk}{\textsc{lnk}}
\newcommand{\loc}{\textsc{loc}}
\newcommand{\mal}{\textsc{mal}}
\newcommand{\Mod}{\textsc{mod}}
\newcommand{\msd}{\textsc{msd}}
\newcommand{\Neg}{\textsc{neg}}
\newcommand{\nml}{\textsc{nml}}
\newcommand{\obl}{\textsc{obl}}
\newcommand{\pl}{\textsc{pl}}
\newcommand{\poss}{\textsc{poss}}
\newcommand{\pot}{\textsc{mod}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\textsc{pp}}
\newcommand{\pr}{\textsc{pr}}
\newcommand{\pred}{\textsc{pred}}
\newcommand{\pst}{\textsc{pst}}
\newcommand{\q}{\textsc{q}}
\newcommand{\re}{\textsc{re}}
\newcommand{\rec}{\textsc{rec}}
\newcommand{\refl}{\textsc{refl}}
\newcommand{\rel}{\textsc{wh}}
\newcommand{\sml}{\textsc{sml}}
\newcommand{\sg}{\textsc{sg}}
\newcommand{\tmp}{\textsc{tmp}}
\newcommand{\trm}{\textsc{inc}}
\newcommand{\wh}{\textsc{wh}}
\newcommand{\nwh}{\textsc{nwh}}
\newcommand{\BF}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\TS}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\TSS}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\LT}[1]{{\Large #1}}
\newcommand{\LLT}[1]{{\LARGE #1}}
\newcommand{\BI}[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FS}[1]{{\footnotesize #1}}
\newcommand{\SC}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\BFSC}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}
\newcommand{\citeposs}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[3]{#2}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \textit{General structure of a West Circassian relative clause}\label{rctree}
%\vspace{12pt}

\hspace*{-3pt}\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a) at (0,0) {\![\TS{CP}~Op\TS{i}~C[\wh]~[\TS{TP}~\ldots~{\it t}\TS{i}~\ldots]]};
\draw[semithick,->] (1.2,-.2)..controls +(south:.5) and +(south:.5)..(-1.3,-.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex {\raisebox{-109pt}{$\hspace*{-6pt}\begin{tabular}[h]{l}%\toprule%[-12pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]\label{bicycletree}
\tikzset{level distance = 25pt}
\Tree
[.CP
    [.\node(op1){\CCh'al-ew\TS{i}}; ]
    [.C$'$
        [.TP
            [.$\textrm{v}$P
                [.DP
                    [.\node(op2){Op\TS{i}}; ]
                    [.PossP \edge[roof]; {~~\underline{\hspace*{0.51cm}}\,\TS{PG}~~z\E-\Sh} ]
                ]
                [.$\textrm{v}'$ \edge[roof]; {~~~{\it t}\TS{i}(\io)~~\O-ze-r-j\E-t\E} ]
            ]
            [.T -\R e ]
        ]
        [.C[\textsc{wh}] ]
    ]
]
\draw[semithick,->] (1,-4.5)..controls +(south:3) and +(south:7)..(op1);
\draw[semithick,->] (-1.5,-5.5)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1)..(op2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}$}}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

These tags working fine, but if I convert `DVIPS --> Convert PDF using Acrobat Distiller` notable to produce PDF, Please suggest what went wrong....

If I run the PS file through AcrobatDistiller, then I got the below errors:

```
%%[ Error: limitcheck; OffendingCommand: save ]%%

Stack:
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-


%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

Comment: Your code compiles correctly with both pdflatex and latex. Furthermore, the conversion with `dvips` is also correct. Could you explain better what the problem is?

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for your reply, if I run the `PS` file through `Acrobat Distiller`, then I got the error as `%%[ Error: limitcheck; OffendingCommand: save ]%%

Stack:
-save-
-save-
%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%`